# unable to debug app in my usb attached mobile via adb and error is mentioned below here

Tags: android, adb

Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --verbose --force-jumbo --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --output C:\Users\Perfect\AndroidStudioProjects\RegistrationPage\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10000\instant-run_00ce957cbbc400d4da775636a5cd1b3714505826 C:\Users\Perfect\AndroidStudioProjects\RegistrationPage\app\build\intermediates\incremental-runtime-classes\debug\instant-run.jar}

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable multiDex in build.gradle:

```
android {

defaultConfig {
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```